# How to Create a Blocking Mask in Unity using Image Components?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm designing a tutorial for a Unity game and am stuck at what seems like a trivial problem. For every step in the tutorial, I guide the user by hiding everything on the screen except the buttons they need to press. My game hierarchy looks like this.

```
Button Canvas
   Select_Me_Button
   Dont_Select_Me_Button
Tutorial Canvas
   Mask Group 1
      Left Border Mask
      Right Border Mask
      Up Border Mask
      Down Border Mask
   Mask Group 2 ...
```

The `TutorialCanvas` GameObject has a Canvas component with a higher sorting order than `ButtonCanvas`. I added `GraphicRaycaster` Component with `Blocking Mask` set to everything and `Blocking Objects` set to None for the TutorialCanvas. However, even though TutorialCanvas renders on top of Button Canvas, I am still able to click through the mask and trigger buttons that are not supposed to be clickable. I was able to block clicks by adding image components functioning as masks to parent objects `Mask Group 1` and `Mask Group 2` belonging to `TutorialCanvas`, but this is not desirable, because I need to group the image components to create a mask, and gameobject can only accept 1 image component.

I'm having a hard time imagining this is so hard. I just need one canvas with a mask to block clicks going to a canvas behind it.

[image]

Comment: Not what you asked but as an alternative solution I would: 1) create an image overlay over the entire screen blocking **everything**. 2) (de)activate exact duplicates of the buttons you already have at the same position with exactly the same callbacks assigned => only this/these exact button/s is/are clickable at all. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a simpler solution. I've tried something like youve suggested, only to get bogged down in syntax. Im hoping to avoid scripting my way out of this.

Comment: Alternative might be using [`CanvasGroups`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) or alternatively simple transparent [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Image.html) components and you simply overlay each individual button with such an image/CanvasGroup => set the [`Image.raycastTarget`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-raycastTarget.html)/[`CanvasGroup.blocksRaycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasGroup-blocksRaycasts.html) for your allowed interactions per step

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help on Unity Forum I solved the issue by creating a single group of masks and positioning them via RectTransform's anchoredPosition component in script.